# data type of value returned from Promise or async / await

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

i know there's a bunch of related questions / posts regarding this question but they don't really answer my question, my question here is simple, if I have a promise and i wrapped it in an async function and await it til it's settled like this:

```
async function getUserData() {
   return fetch('url'); // fetch returns a promise, wrapping the user data returned
}

async main() {
   const user = await getUserData();
   // what is the type of the user object here?
}
```

I'm asking this question because I'm using TypeScript, I usually try to type cast the return value to the expected type like this:

```
async function getUserData() {
   return fetch('url') as UserInfo; 
}
```

say UserInfo has a name attribute but if I try write in this way then user.name is undefined:

```
async function main() {
   const user = await getUserData();
   console.log(user.name); // undefined.
}
```

it makes me how should I 'unwrap' a promise with a value in it?

Comment: Not sure, but what if you cast it to `as Promise<Userinfo>` or something like that? (im not a typescripter, just a regular js'er, sorry)

Comment: 1) fetch already returns a promise (thus also casting to `UserInfo` makes no sense), no need to mark the function async in your first snippets. 2) the return type of an async function is `Promise<T>` where T is the type of the thing the promise resolves to. 3) I would wager that UserInfo is the type of the JSON data. In that case, use an async function and await the JSON and return that, then the return type is `Promise<UserInfo>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really know at compile time what it is, because this is explicitly something that happens at runtime.

So usually the result of a `JSON.parse()` is `any`. A stricter version could be the `unknown` type.

If you want to just *assume* whatever you got back is going to be the right type, without validating (because you trust the server), I think I would do that as such:

```js
async function getUserData(): Promise<UserInfo> {
   return fetch('url'); // fetch returns a promise, wrapping the user data returned
}
```

Comment: the compile time / running time really clears the confusion. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think the way that Async/Await works is that it wraps the function in a native promise.

I tested out your examples in the browser console and both functions return a Promise.

```
Promise {<pending>}
```

I am not sure about what that is cast to in Typescript as I don't use it. But if you drop into the browser console you can test all of this. It functions as a pretty good REPL.

As a function of design, the getUserData() function does not need to be async as you are not awaiting anything in it.

As for unwrapping it, you can use the fetch API since you now have a fetch result:

```
const data = getUserData();
data.then(response => response.json())
```